# Populate dropdown with data through two models CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This is a very specific question but I am currently stuck. I have a standard belongsToMany relationship populating one multi-select with data from the target table. The tables are linked like so:

Table1 <-> Link Table <-> Table 2

The controller associated with Table 2 contains this:

```
$table1 = $this->Table2->Table1->find('all');
```

Fine - all working. The problem I have is when I try to use data one step beyond this. What do I mean? Well, I'm using a another table that is populated with fks, so I need to follow the fk to get actual presentable data. To illustrate:

Table1 <-> Link Table <-> Table 3 <-> OptionsTable1

So Table3 would have an id and a number pulled from OptionsTable1 (which populates a dropdown in the view associated with it - in the /add page). I would like, in the add page associated with Table1, to be able to pull data from OptionsTable1 through Table3. Otherwise all I can get is a list of numbers, which is no good to anyone. I did try this:

```
$label = $this->Table1->Table3->OptionsTable1->find('all');
```

But so far it's not working.

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, It will be solved using `contain`.
Something like `$options['contain'] = ['Table3' => ['OptionsTable1']]` and then `$this->Table1->find('all', $options)`. If the associations are made correctly in `Table1` and `Table3` and `OptionsTable1` then it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, it results in a 'Error: Method Cake\ORM\Query::__toString() must not throw an exception' being thrown.

Comment: Okay, I took what you suggested and got some info from the Cake3 book. I arrived at the following:    $label = $this->Table1->Table3->find('all', ['contain' => ['OptionsTable1']]); It works, but will only return the id from OptionsTable1. I need the other column (there's only two in that table - id and contents). Getting there, slowly...

Comment: This link might help you. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations. Eager Loading is a very nice concept. You will learn that you can link association upto n-th level. (any level deep)